# How many number of BLE peripheral could be connected with iPhone (iOS) at a time?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an application which required to connect multiple BLE peripheral device with iPhone. I want to know a maximum number of BLE peripheral that can connect with iPhone at a time.

I have already tried with 10 devices. I was able to connect 10 BLE peripheral with the iPhone. Since I don't have more devices, I was not able to test further. Please let me know the maximum number of BLE peripheral devices that could be connected with iPhone at a time.

Is there any limit in BLE peripheral connection that only this number of devices could be connected with this specific application? or It is managed by iOS itself?